# Maven command to run activemq before intergation tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, jms, activemq-classic

I need to run ActiveMQ in my maven clean install, so that it starts up activemq and then runs my tests. I have included the plugin in pom.xml and added the mq config file for configuring mq details. It runs successfully and all test pass when I run activeMq on one console and run maven clean install on others (2 separate commands on 2 separate consoles). But is there a way I can run activemq and clean install both with 1 command on the same console? Basically I wish that when I do **mvn clean test install**, it should automatically fire-up mq first and then proceed with the tests...

I have tried using commands like **mvn activemq:run clean test install** or **mvn clean test install activemq:run**. But it either does the clean install or runs the activemq...

How do I combine these 2 commands(**activemq:run** and **mvn clean test install**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attach the maven goal and plugin using the `<build><plugins>` construct.**:

```
<build>   
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-activemq-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase> <!-- or other phase before the test phase -->
                </execution>
            </executions>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Perfect... and how do I refer to the phase "pre-integration-test" under <phase></phase>?

Comment: You don't. Look at the https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html. The phase is automatically part of the default build lifecycle and will be automatically executed before the test phase you are executing manually.

Comment: I see... that makes sense.. Now my activemq ran before I added this successfully. But after adding the above lines when I run it, I get the following exception:-      "Plugin org.apache.activemq.tooling:maven-activemq-plugin:5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.activemq.tooling:maven-activemq-plugin:jar:5.1 in http://subversion.xx.xx.xx/svn/repos/mavenRepository/trunk/m2repository-XXXX-release/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of XXX-m2-repo has elapsed or updates are forced ->"

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I appreciate it a lot. Its working now and my tests are using the activeMQ instance to run the integration tests. I am using the uri :- **"tcp://localhost:61616?useJmx=false&amp;persistent=false&amp;fork=true"** and phase as **"pre-integration-test"** in my pom.xml. I removed the camel and jetty dependencies as I do not need it. Only thing is that I see the logs when any message is transferred to the queue, and I see a variety of port numbers instead of 61616.. For eg, tcp://127.0.0.1:49921, tcp://127.0.0.1:49920, tcp://127.0.0.1:49921/49827/49829 etc..

Comment: Is this considered valid and okay? I ask because if I run activeMQ in a separate instance, I get 61616 every time and it does not use any other ports.

Comment: I can see the active mq has started in "process-test-classes" phase. But then the whole build stops there. How can I proceed to my tests ?