# How to start activemq before your tests and move over to the tests

Tags: maven, automation, activemq-classic

I am trying to test my application which send s a message to a queue (Activemq).

I have a maven test project where it can consume from the javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer.

If I am to start the activemq within the maven build, I was following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307763/maven-command-to-run-activemq-before-intergation-tests/). But that will stop at the point it starts the activemq, and do not move over the build to the test execution.

My build xml section looks like below,

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-activemq-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase> 
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am looking for a way to let maven to move over to the next phase once the activemq started.

I also tried the newer version of the plugin, which is *activemq-maven-plugin*;

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Either case my maven build stops at ...

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-automation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\xyz\my-automation\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-activemq-plugin:5.7.0:run (default) @ my-automation ---
[INFO] Loading broker configUri: broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)?useJmx=false&persistent=false
[INFO] Using Persistence Adapter: MemoryPersistenceAdapter
[INFO] Apache ActiveMQ 5.7.0 (localhost, ID:XYZ-0001:1) is starting
[INFO] Listening for connections at: tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
[INFO] Connector tcp://127.0.0.1:61616 Started
[INFO] Apache ActiveMQ 5.7.0 (localhost, ID:XYZ-0001:1) started
[INFO] For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
```

Which is the point where activemq has started.

How can I proceed from this point ?

Comment: Why not just use an embedded broker in a unit test?  What is the reason driving this?

Comment: Hi @TimBish, Yes as a plan B I have already started using the embedded broker  in my integration tests.  

Keep a note this is not for unit testing, and this is for some integration testing. 

My thinking behind getting this out of test code, is just because the MQ is part of application which I am testing, so don't want to have test code for bringing up application components.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your plugin declaration:

```
<configuration>
    <fork>true</fork>
</configuration>
```